# How do you get specify html text from bs4 parsed response?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am using this code to parse some context form a [url](http://%27https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/tech/1065005.htm%27):

```
response = requests.get(url)
cnbeta_article_content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser").find("div", {"class": "cnbeta-article-body"})
return cnbeta_article_content.contents
```

But I need to get the cnbeta_article_content.contents was a result of list. How do you get the plain html from class `cnbeta-article-body` of the url? The `cnbeta_article_content.text` is not the original html.

Comment: pls give some more details(like url). what you desire is not clear

Comment: I have added the url am pull from @bipin_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does cnbeta_article_content.prettify() render what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting multiple results for the class so you will have to find out which one should you pick. If possible use a unique selector for the specific element or you can extract it from the current list (cnbeta_article_content.contents)

Go to the website and find out the elements serial number (I mean you are getting multiple elements with the same class so what is the position of your expected element) for the class you mentioned. You will get the text like this

```
cnbeta_article_content.contents[4].text
```

Here 4 is the 5th element (Zero indexing system)